# Location of source code to System.Web.Razor.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I have searched Codeplex, NuGet and Google with

```
"system.web.razor" +source
```

and I cannot find Microsoft's source code to the latest Razor Template Engine, **System.Web.Razor.dll**. I thought this was supposed to be open-source? Has anyone the link to the source repository for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of this assembly is in the System.Web.Razor project in the [download of the source of ASP.NET MVC3](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781).  I was incorrect when I posted an answer before.